# How to create my own promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have two questions about promises in AngularJS:

1. How do I create my own promise?

See the code below:

```
function controller($http) {
     var dataCache;

     function getData(){        

        if( dataCache != null ){
             // should return my own promise here 
             // to pass the value of 'dataCache' to 'then' immediately
        } else {
            return $http.get('...some url ...');
        }
    }
}
```

1. How do I return the last promise?

Code:

```
function controller($http) {

     var urlArr = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3'];

     function getDataOneByOne() {
          // should call $http.get() for the url in the 'urlArr' one after another in a chain
          // and return the last promise
     }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: Please write one question per post in the future. Try to write your posts in a way that they will be most helpful to the community (future viewers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second question, do [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) on `urlArr` and build promise chain:

```
function controller($http, $q) {

    var urlArr = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3'];

    function getDataOneByOne() {
        return urlArr.reduce(function (chain, url) {
            return chain.then(function () {
                return $http.get(url);
            });
        }, $q.when());
    }
}
```

Don't forget to handle $http errors, though.

Comment: Nice, you beat me to to it and did a nicer job anyway. Complete promise libraries have a nicer solution for this sort of thing, but this is good for the limited Angular `$q` api.

Answer (score 2):

For the first question, I believe you're looking for `$q.when()`. It wraps a normal value in a promise and resolves it.

```
function getData(){        

  if( dataCache !== null ) {
    $q.when(dataCache);      
  } else {
    return $http.get('...some url ...');
  }

}

getData.then(function() {

});
```

See Klaster's answer for your second question.